# How to check whether a word is abbreviated or not using Python?

Tags: machine-learning, language, python

How do I check whether a word is abbreviated or not in a dataframe column using Python? For instance, I need to detect the value "U.S.A." as an abbreviation.
Is there any dictionary present for this?

Comment: See these discussions: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20727552/abbreviation-detection, https://www.researchgate.net/post/What_is_the_best_technique_to_detect_abbreviations_in_a_text

Comment: You’re kidding right? Just think, you can be the first to create one

Comment: Do you mean [acronym](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/acronym) or [abbreviation](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/abbreviation)?

Comment: if it's "acronym", check out these answers: https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/4812/1511

Answer (score 0):

If it is the general problem of trying to find if any substring within any string is an abbreviation, that will be computationally intractable (especially within a Pandas DataFrame).

If it is a single column that could only be countries, you could do item-by-item fuzzy comparisons using [fuzzywuzzy](https://github.com/seatgeek/fuzzywuzzy) and [pycountry](https://pypi.org/project/pycountry/) packages.

It could be something like this:

```
import pandas as pd
import pycountry
from fuzzywuzzy import process

# Mock data
df = pd.DataFrame(data={'country': ['U.S.A.', 'Westeros']})

# A dict with 3 letter abbreviation and full country name
country_abbreviations = {country.alpha_3:country.name for country in pycountry.countries}

def guess_country(abbreviation_raw):
    "Return best guess for country match and ratio of match"
    # Find best guess based on fuzzy match 
    abbreviation_guess, confidence = process.extractOne(abbreviation_raw, country_abbreviations.keys())
    full_name = country_abbreviations[abbreviation_guess]
    return abbreviation_raw, abbreviation_guess, full_name, confidence

df.country.apply(guess_country)
```

which returns

```
0    (U.S.A., USA, United States, 75)
1        (Westeros, EST, Estonia, 90)
Name: country, dtype: object
```

Comment: i need all abbreviation words not only countries. Is it possible to get all

Comment: It is possible. The first step is to create a hash map of all possible abbreviations and their expanded phrases. Then go through token-by-token to identify possible matches. Possible does not mean computationally feasible.

Comment: where i can get hash map of all possible abbreviations