# Business term abbreviation dataset

Tags: data-request

I'm looking for a list containing common abbreviations for business terms. For example, "revenue" --> "rev.".

I found this [post](https://opendata.stackexchange.com/questions/4812/list-of-abbreviations-and-acronyms) but that links to *common* acronyms and abbreviations.

A friendly format would be great, but even if I could scrape to collect this stuff that would be helpful.

(Of course, the problem of converting a given word into an abbreviation seems like a very extensive NLP project, which I'd like to avoid.)

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own from these lists:
[List of business and finance abbreviations on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_business_and_finance_abbreviations)
[Business Abbreviations on All Acronyms](https://www.allacronyms.com/business/abbreviations)
[Business Industry Search on fullformgo](https://www.fullformgo.com/terms?search=A&cat_name=Business%20%26%20Industry&page=1)

Comment: Note: If you choose this/similar path, it would be swell if you published the list as open data, and came back here and shared the list's uri/the list with us!