# Dataset for company name aliases

Tags: companies

I am looking for a dataset or service providing company name aliases. For example HP == Hewlett Packard, PWC = Price Waterhouse Coopers.

Is there such a dataset or service?

Comment: related: https://opendata.stackexchange.com/q/4812/1511